# Svn: added files but deleted few before committing: not able to commit now

Tags: svn

I added few files to svn repository. But before I do commit, I deleted some of the pdf files. Now when I do a svn  commit it syas ".pdf' is scheduled for addition, but is missing
". Please let me know is there a way to come out of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete a file from repository - you need to explicitly specify that to svn. So perform

```
svn del filename
```

where `filename` is the path to the file that you has deleted already (the one which is missing)

Comment: I used svn revert filename and then did commit. It worked fine.

Comment: Indeed - in this case "revert" and "del" do the same thing.